# React Redux: 'X is not a function' after using mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Very new to Redux. I'm following an example at my work place to try and create a Facebook Login button using a stateless component. I can't seem to do the basic thing of binding the `clickHandler` property to a function of any description. I've reduced it to a simply console log in the below example. Whatever I do, when I click the button I get 'clickHandler is not a function'. What am I doing wrong?

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';

const FacebookLoginComponent = (props) => {
    const {
        clickHandler
    } = props;
    return(
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={ () => clickHandler() }>Say hello</button>
    )
}
export default FacebookLoginComponent;
```

**Container**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import FacebookLoginComponent from "../components/FacebookLogin";

const mapStateToProps = state => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    clickHandler: () => console.log('hello')
})

const FacebookLogin = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(FacebookLoginComponent);

export default FacebookLogin;
```

Comment: Your code look OK to me, does the connect succed? Try to add in the returned object a `console.log`, so it is triggered directly.

Comment: Are you definitely using the connected `FacebookLogin` and not the "dumb" `FacebookLogin` by mistake? If you were using the `FacebookLogin` and not passing in any props then `clickHandler` would indeed not be a function

Comment: Make a sandbox example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you might be using the unconnected `FacebookLoginComponent` by mistake instead of the connected `FacebookLogin`.

If you were using the `FacebookLoginComponent` and not passing in any props then clickHandler would indeed not be a function.

Comment: Happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the click handler inside the mapDispatchToProps function, which is used for dispatching actions to the store. Usually, you would not define event handlers in your mapStateToProps or mapDispatchToProps functions. It should work if you put it in your mapStateToProps function but I would rather just define it in your component like so:

```
import React from 'react';

const FacebookLoginComponent = (props) => {
    const clickHandler = () => console.log("Hello World");

    return(
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={clickHandler}>Say hello</button>
    )
}
export default FacebookLoginComponent;
```

And remove it from your container.

You would also wrap your actions with dispatch() in your mapDispatchToProps handler, as demonstrated here: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: I do understand this concept, and the original implementation is `clickHandler: () => dispatch(loginWithFacebook())` with `loginWithFacebook` being successfully imported, but I get the same error.

Comment: I made a working CodeSandbox example for you https://codesandbox.io/s/r4mm472v3p. It works with your initial code

Comment: I was using the unconnected component. D'oh!